# Sharepoint 2013 : Run any other javascript after the Display Templates have have rendered the content

Tags: sharepoint

1. I create a ContentBySearchWebpart, specified my custom Display templates.
2. wanted to run some other javascript code, after the Display
   Templates have rendered the content
3. Registered my custom javascript file in Display template.

   ```
           $includeScript(this.url, "~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/Display Templates/Slider.js");
   ```
4. The Problem is that, my Slider.js file code executes before Display
   Templates Javascript code.
   Can anybody provide me a way to run my Slider.js code after the display templates have rendered the content of ContentBySearchWebpart(CSWP).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

:) my issue is solved.

I did following :

1. Registered the custom JS file in Control_YourTemplateName.html
   file(like Control_Banner)

   $includeScript(this.url, "~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/Display Templates/HWScripts/Banner.js");

Added these three lines under the first div after body tag, in YourTemplateName.html ( like Banner.html) file.

```
<!--#_

ctx.OnPostRender = [];

ctx.OnPostRender.push(function(){ 
CustomMethodWhichIsIncludedInTheCustomJSFile();
});
 _#-->
```